# JET Excelsior create exe for 32 bit

Tags: java

I am using jet excelsior for creating an exe file from a java project.

my question is if I can configure the settings to create an exe file that will be installed on a 32 bit computer.

my computer is 64 bit and if I create the exe in it using jet excelsior version 12, the created exe file is failing to be installed on a 32 bit computer.

can someone help me figure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 variants of Excelsior JET distributions. If you want a 32-bit compatible binary you should build with 32-bit distribution

This is info from **32 bit vs 64 bit** section of their [evaluation page](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate):

> Which version to evaluate: 32‑bit or 64‑bit?
>
> As of version 12.0, 32‑bit Excelsior JET provides more features (see Release Notes below), and often delivers better application performance, but the final choice depends on your target platform(s):
>
> Windows: 32‑bit executables install and work normally on 64‑bit Windows systems, so if Windows is your sole target, evaluate the 64‑bit version only if your application requires a large heap and/or needs to integrate with 64‑bit native libraries.
>
> Linux: Installation of 32‑bit libraries on 64‑bit Linuces is often cumbersome, so you may need to provide both 64‑bit and 32‑bit Linux builds to your end users.
>
> OS X: The OS X version of Excelsior JET is 64‑bit only, so you don't really have a choice.

Comment: Thanks Aleh for that answer.But i'm unable to install the 32-bit .exe on my computer. The 64-bit is working alright on my pc.This is the error when installing the 32 -bit "Unable to decompress:installation package is corrupted".I tried downloading it  again but still facing the same issue.Any help please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I know it from Linux and there you have 32-bit OS for 32-bit builds and 64-bit OS for 64-bit builds.